# Bootstrap Form Helper - Select country dynamically on Country picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, bootstrap-form-helper

I'm using country picker from Bootstrap form helper:
[Country Picker](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/country/)

Problem is that i need to initialize it dynamically with a country. I'm using data-country="US" as default, anyways i need to change it on document ready function.

```
      <div id="country-select" class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-flags="true" data-value="US">
        <input type="hidden" value="">
        <a class="bfh-selectbox-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="bfh-selectbox" href="#">
          <span class="bfh-selectbox-option input-medium" data-option=""></span>
          <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <div class="bfh-selectbox-options">
          <input type="text" class="bfh-selectbox-filter">
          <div role="listbox">
          <ul role="option">
          </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: your html is wrong. This is not how countrypicker is initialized. **This is the html after initialization** `<select  id="country-select" name="country-select" class="form-control bfh-countries" data-country="US" data-flags="true"></select>` is how you should have been initializing it. Also be clear on what you are trying to do. There are 2 things that you say you **need to do**

Comment: How do i initialize it? If i use the code you provided the select is empty. My code instead is working well

Comment: have you included `bootstrap-formhelpers.js` to your html?

Comment: And you also need to put that select inside a form tag(although this needless to say since you are using a bootstrap plugin). See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xyL9u6e/5/)

Comment: In the fiddle i can't select a country dinamically with:
$('#country-select').bfhcountries({country: 'TN'});

Comment: did you execute the code in the frame or the main document?

Comment: once you declare it in html form, all you need to do is `$('#country-select').val(cc);` see [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xyL9u6e/17/)

Comment: The fiddle is working perfectly. But in my application i set value correctly ( i can get the correct value back), but the select is not updating. It keeps staying on united states. Damn

Comment: Have you declared it as i did, with html? If so please check that the id of the select is same in your code and you have jquery. If you declare it with a div, the select will have a different id than your div. That's why i asked you to declare it by html

Comment: Yes, id is the same. I can change and retrive val, but the select stays on united states

Comment: Do you have any other components that messes up with selects? Like bootstrap selectpicker?

Comment: or can you supply us a test page where we can see the code and advise accordingly?

Comment: I'm using absolute admin bootstrap template. Probably it break up something with this country select

Comment: see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the html below to select a default country on initialize. Also add `bootstrap-formhelpers.js` and `bootstrap-formhelpers.css` to your html or your select **will not** be populated with data.

```
<form><select  id="country-select" name="country-select" class="form-control bfh-countries" data-country="US" data-flags="true"></select></form>
```

and to select a country after initialization,

```
$('#country-select').val('TN');
```

see the [document](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/country/#example1) for more options on initilization.
Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xyL9u6e/17/).

**Per OP's comment** The OP is using a theme using [select2](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items), quoting from there

> Select2 will listen for the change event on the  element that it is attached to. When you make any external changes that need to be reflected in Select2 (such as changing the value), you should trigger this event.

and therefore to reflect changes;

```
  $('#country-select').val('TN').trigger('change');
```

Comment: No way... even with triggering change event the select keeps staying on united states

Comment: please show an example page so we can move further, otherwise this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Solved, i call an Elixir view function that populate data-country on rendering. Anyways i'll mark your as accepted answer, because it's working for those who have no libraries conflicts

Answer (score 2):

From the [Example 3](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/country/), you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#country-select').bfhcountries({country: 'TN'});
});
```

```js
$('#LoadCountry').click(function(){
  $('#countries1').bfhcountries({country: 'TN'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-formhelpers/2.3.0/js/bootstrap-formhelpers.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-formhelpers/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-formhelpers.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button id='LoadCountry' class="btn">Load Countries</button>
<br><br>
<select id="countries1" class="form-control"></select>
```

Comment: Already tried, i'm getting: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bfhcountries is not a function

Comment: you need to include `bootstrap-formhelpers.js` and `bootstrap-formhelpers.css` to your page.

Comment: I've them included. Can you please me provide a js fiddle for that? I can't get this working, i'm getting mad

Comment: @Razinar check the snippet above!